# Visual Source Safe 6.0 compatibility with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-sourcesafe, sourcesafe-6.0

I'm currently involved in a technology upgrade project in my company, and would like to know if VSS6.0 is compatible with latest Visual Studio 2015?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

VSS is not included since VS 2010 due to performance issues. According to

[Can I Use Visual Source Safe with Visual studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970797/can-i-use-visual-source-safe-with-visual-studio-2013)

and

[Visual Studio 2015 Professional and Visual SourceSafe (VSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291555/visual-studio-2015-professional-and-visual-sourcesafe-vss)

you can choose "Microsoft Visual SourceSafe" plugin from Tools -> Options -> Source Control.

I suggest you to use TFS/CVS/Git/SVN rather than VSS for better version control of your application.